# Container view width decreases after adding safe area constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have a `ViewController` and a container view `testcontrollerViewController` inside of it. I noticed that after I'm adding constraints to that container view in the storyboard (all the edges match the safe area) its width decreases a little bit, but if I remove constraints width changes back to normal. (Switches from 724px to 712px and back)

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

I print container view width in its `viewDidAppear` function.

```
class testcontrollerViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    print("container vc load \(testview.frame.width)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("container vc appear \(testview.frame.width)")
    print("container view safe area insets \(view.safeAreaInsets)")
}

@IBOutlet var testview: UIView!
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think because there is a gap between the superview and safearea. When you constraints the container view it relates to the safearea only - I think that is the reason the width changed above.